# How to change data while recyclerview is computing? IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

I got a problem with data changing. Everything works fine till I press my TextView tvMinusSeconds or tvAddSeconds (minus or ads 10 seconds to my countdowntimer) because after my countdowntimer countdown to 0 it throws an `IllegalStateException`.

I tried to change notifyDataSetChanged() to >>codes below<< from onFinish() method but it stops my new countdown for (times clicked* 10 seconds) or just don't work at all. How can I refresh my data and not get `IllegalStateException`?

```
if (mRecyclerView != null && !mRecyclerView.isComputingLayout()) 
{
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This from another topic doesn't help me either:

```
dialeecyclerView.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        });
```

- 

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
 public void run() {
      // UI code goes here
 }
 });
```

- 

```
 public class TimerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TimerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 static ArrayList<Timer> timers;
 Context context;




public TimerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Timer> list) {
  this.timers = list;
    this.context = context;

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RecyclerView rvChannelsList;
    CountDownTimer timer;
    TextView tvNextRespTime, tvRespTime, tvTimerName, tvTimeCounter, tvRestartTime,  tvAddSeconds, tvMinusSeconds;

    ImageView ivDelete;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);


        rvChannelsList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvChannelsList);

        tvNextRespTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNextRespTime);
        tvRespTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRespTime);
        tvTimerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimerName);
        tvTimeCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeCounter);
        tvRestartTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRestartTime);

        tvAddSeconds = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddSeconds);
        tvMinusSeconds = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMinusSeconds);
        ivDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);



        tvAddSeconds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                timers.get(position).setPlusTime( timers.get(position).getPlusTime()+10000);
                MainActivity.getmInstanceActivity().saveTimersData();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }



        });

        tvMinusSeconds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                timers.get(position).setMinusTime(timers.get(position).getMinusTime()+10000);
                MainActivity.getmInstanceActivity().saveTimersData();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                timers.remove(position);
                MainActivity.getmInstanceActivity().saveTimersData();
                notifyItemRemoved(position);

            }
        });
    }

}

@NonNull
@Override
public TimerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TimerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {      


    holder.itemView.setTag(timers.get(position));
    holder.tvTimerName.setText(timers.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvRespTime.setText(millisToStringHMS(timers.get(position).getTimeOfNextResp()));


    final String dateStr = getCurrentTimeString();


    long respTimeInMillis = stringToMillisHm(timers.get(position).getTime());
    long currentTimeInMillis = stringToMillisHMS(dateStr);
    int compare = Long.compare(respTimeInMillis, currentTimeInMillis);  // respTimeInMillis < currentTimeInMillis
//        if (compare > 0) {  // respTimeInMillis > currentTimeInMillis
        if (respTimeInMillis > currentTimeInMillis) {  // respTimeInMillis > currentTimeInMillis
            while (currentTimeInMillis + timers.get(position).getTimeOfNextResp() < respTimeInMillis) {
            currentTimeInMillis = currentTimeInMillis + timers.get(position).getTimeOfNextResp();

        }
    } else {
        while (respTimeInMillis < currentTimeInMillis + timers.get(position).getTimeOfNextResp()) {
            respTimeInMillis = respTimeInMillis + timers.get(position).getTimeOfNextResp();

        }

        if (respTimeInMillis - currentTimeInMillis > timers.get(position).getTimeOfNextResp()) {
            respTimeInMillis -= timers.get(position).getTimeOfNextResp();
        }
    }

    holder.tvRestartTime.setText(timers.get(position).getTime());


    long difference = respTimeInMillis - currentTimeInMillis - timers.get(position).getMinusTime() + timers.get(position).getPlusTime();

    holder.tvNextRespTime.setText(nextRespTime(difference));

    final long[] counter = {difference};
    //Very important code for some problems
    if (holder.timer != null) {
        holder.timer.cancel();
    }

    holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(counter[0], 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            counter[0] = millisUntilFinished;
            int hours = (int) (counter[0] / 1000) / 3600;
            int minutes = (int) (counter[0] / 1000) / 60;
            int seconds = (int) (counter[0] / (double) 1000) % 60;

            String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

            holder.tvTimeCounter.setText(timeLeftFormatted);

            if (millisUntilFinished < 59000) {
                holder.tvTimeCounter.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.timerColor2));
            } else {
                holder.tvTimeCounter.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.timerColor1));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            start();
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.start();

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return timers.size();
}
```

- 

```
public class ListTimerFrag extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;


 //RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    View view;
    private TimerAdapter myAdapter;


public ListTimerFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_timer, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listOfTimers);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    myAdapter = new TimerAdapter(this.getActivity(),ApplicationDataClass.timers);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);



}

public void notifyDataChanged(){
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}