# How to make my program 'remember' what i clicked? //EDITED

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

//EDIT 2 /// I tried to make shared preferiences to remember my all marks from second adapter. So i made 2 string arrays to remember they keys (my channels max numbers equals 8). In my second recycler view i set my channels booleans marks to shared preferiences with keys from data[]. In my main recyclers view i set multidimensional array

```
 boolean[][] tab = new boolean[ApplicationDataClass.timers.size()][8];
```

and inside onBindViewHolder i set a loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i <8 ; i++) {
        tab[position][i]=dataProccessor.getBool(data[i]);
        dataProccessor.setBool(keyChTab[i],tab[position][i]);
    }
```

that copy booleans to that multidimensional array (with position of main recyclerview) and copy it back to keyChTab[].
I know its hardcode but i tried to make it by myself but failed. Could you please help me fix it? How to set those shared preferiences? Oh and the problem is my multidimensional array dont work like i want it to work. Because it remember one set of booleans and all items from main recycler view got same marks. I cannot unlick marked items and when i mark channel 1  its marking all channels 1 on the list

Second RecyclerView:

```
public class ChannelsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelsRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context applicationContext = MainActivity.getContextOfApplication();
    DataProccessor dataProccessor = new DataProccessor(applicationContext);
    String[] keyChTab = {"keyChTab0", "keyChTab1", "keyChTab2", "keyChTab3", "keyChTab4", "keyChTab5", "keyChTab6", "keyChTab7"};
String[] data = {"d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7"};

boolean[] isClicked = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,};
ArrayList<String> arrayList;


public ChannelsRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_children_layout, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tvChannels.setText(arrayList.get(position));

        isClicked[position] = dataProccessor.getBool(keyChTab[position]);
        if (isClicked[position]) {
            holder.tvChannels.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_text_view_red);
        }

    holder.tvChannels.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isClicked[position]) {
                holder.tvChannels.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor1));
                holder.tvChannels.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_text_view_white);
                isClicked[position] = false;
            } else {
                holder.tvChannels.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor2));
                holder.tvChannels.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_text_view_red);
                isClicked[position] = true;
            }
            dataProccessor.setBool(data[position], isClicked[position]);
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvChannels;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvChannels = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvChannels);
    }
}

public void setToFalse(String[] tab) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        dataProccessor.setBool(tab[i], false);
    }
}
```

}

DataProccessor:

```
public class DataProccessor {

private static Context context;

public DataProccessor(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public final static String PREFS_NAME = "appname_prefs";

public boolean sharedPreferenceExist(String key)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if(!prefs.contains(key)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void setInt( String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public int getInt(String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    return prefs.getInt(key, 0);
}

public void setStr(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public String getStr(String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    return prefs.getString(key,"DNF");
}

public  void setBool(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public  boolean getBool(String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    return prefs.getBoolean(key,false);
}
```

}

Comment: store it somewhere.

Comment: Follow this tutorial. Use Shared Preferences to save the selected items and you will be able to use it anywhere in your application. https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: You are saving them already in 
boolean[] isClicked={false}; Dont use shared preferences.

Comment: When my main RecyclerView countdowntimer reach 0 it resets marks from all countdowns thats why i need to save it somewhere

Comment: @KalanaChinthaka could you please help me with shared preferences? I updated my problem and now my marks are even when i minimalize my program but still when my countdowntimer from main recyclerview countdown to 0 it reset all marks from second recyclerview . Should i somehow save those marks in main recyclerview? Or how can i do that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a class of SharedPrefrence & use its reference everywhere you need to store or retrieve your values. it's simple, if you need any more help, you can ask how to do that.

Edit ------

```
import android.text.TextUtils;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SharedPreferencesSample {
    public static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String PREF_USERNAME = "username";

    private static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "test_preferences";
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public SharedPreferencesSample (Context context) {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);
    }

    public void put(String name, String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(name, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String get(String name) {
        return prefs.getString(name, "");
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return get(PREF_PASSWORD);
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        put(PREF_PASSWORD, password);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return get(PREF_USERNAME);
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        put(PREF_USERNAME, userName);
    }
}
```

> This was the class file

Heres the usage for it -

```
private SharedPreferencesSample prefs = new SharedPreferencesSample (this);

prefs.getUserName(); //Get Username
prefs.getPassword(); //Get Password
prefs.setUserName("username"); //Set Username
prefs.setPassword("password"); //Set Password
```

Comment: okay let me edit the answer, i will add the class & its usage

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got one more problem with my main RecyclerView. Could you please look  at it?   [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447232/how-to-change-data-while-recyclerview-is-computing-illegalstateexception) Im new in programming and trying to make evrything by my own but sometimes its to hard (I don't have the proper knowledge to do it right)

Comment: Use the pattern to store any type of thing you want

Comment: @RafałDytrych change it with SharedPreferencesSample ... sry i didnt change the name properly... check the new edit

Comment: I edited my problem 1 minute ago, could you look at it one more time? I did shared preferences with your help and with help of another stackoverflow page.

Comment: I did it after your answer buy... "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."... ;P

Comment: @RafałDytrych thats fine thanks, try saving your marks in shared prefrence as well

Comment: could you please look one more time and say what im doing wrong? Failed to save those marks by my own ;/

Comment: I'm confused by your code, where & how are you using sharedPreferenceExist(key), & inside it, I again cant understand it good, ```if(!prefs.contains(key))``` if prefs contains the key you must return true, isn't it? the IF ELSE part is shuffled compared with your method name sharedPreferenceExist();

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did fix it yesterday by my own (so proud :D)

Comment: @RafałDytrych that's great, good luck for further things :)